# WPF UserControlから親Windowの要素を操作する。

Tags: c#, wpf

ご教授お願いします。

UserControlに配置されているボタンをクリックすると、親Windowに配置されているTitleLinksをクリックした時と同じ挙動を実現したいです。
親Windowのソースは以下の通りです。(ModernUI for WPFを使っています。)

```html
<!--親Window-->
<mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Menu1表示" Source="/menu1.xaml" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Menu2表示" Source="/menu2.xaml" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Menu3表示" Source="/menu3.xaml" />
    </mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
```

子のUserControlでは

```html
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var Oya =(MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
  //ここに親Windowsの、あるTitleLinksをクリックした時の挙動を追加したい。
}
```

とすることで、Oya.TitleLinkから３つのメニューのSourceプロパティを確認する事ができます。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自力で解決できました。　方法をこちらに記載します。

[参考にしたページはこちらです。](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249707/modern-ui-how-to-go-to-another-page-from-another-link)

以下のようにコードを追加しました。 TitleLinks[0]のページに遷移するサンプルです。

```html
using System.Windows.Input;
using FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var Oya =(MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
  IInputElement target = NavigationHelper.FindFrame("_top", Oya);
  NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute(Oya.TitleLinks[0].Source, target);
}
```